# How to retrieve value from database and display in textbox

Tags: mysql, vb6

I am using vb6, and the database is mysql. There is this table called "absen", it has a field called "tglabsen" which storing dates in this format : dd/mm/yyyy. I tried to find records according to the date. 
eg. find records who have dates between 01/01/2017 to 01/02/2017

My question is how to store the number in a variable, and then display it in a textbox? What I tried so far, I tested this :

```
number = "Select count(*) from absen where tglabsen >='" & DTPicker1 & "' and tglabsen <='" & DTPicker2 & "'"

KON.Execute number

txtjumlahabsen = number
```

But the textbox (`txtjumlahabsen`) is just showing the sql query above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KON.Execute` just executes the sql statement you stored in your `number` variable. It doesn't update the variable with the data, which is why your textbox is showing the sql statement.

You need to open a recordset to retrieve the data:

```
Dim rs as New Recordset
Dim countVal as Integer

number = "Select count(*) from absen where tglabsen >='" & DTPicker1 & "' and tglabsen <='" & DTPicker2 & "'"

rs.Open number, KON, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
If Not rs.EOF then
   countVal = rs(0).Value
End If
rs.Close

txtjumlahabsen.Text = countVal
```

If your sql statement is successful, the value from `count(*)` will be applied to the `countVal` variable. If it is not successful, `countVal` will remain at zero.

Comment: Looks like your code does not work, it remains 0 even though in the table, there are records

Comment: @AgilGA You might want to check your sql statement in mysql to see if your date ranges are returning anything or not. You may need to format your DTPicker1.Value to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format for it to work.

Comment: Why do i need to change the format? the "tglabsen" field's data type is varchar though, not date. And the string format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @AgilGAI rolled back my edit. Normally, when one asks a question, they put pertinent information IN the question so people can accurately answer based on the situation. Getting back to the issue, run your sql statement with the values you are trying to pull via MySql, not in code, to ensure your query actually works.

Comment: 1. 

Sorry if my question is not too detailed. 
You mean like test it right in phpmyadmin, not in vb?

Comment: 1 

Your is actually code working like a charm. So this is what happened, i chose 012 as NIP, and set the date via DTPicker between 24 june 2017 to 25 july. However, in the table, employee with NIP 012 only had 1 record with status ='absen masuk', and its in 10 june 2017. Hahahahahahahahaha.....

Thats it, thats how stupid i am, and i think case closed. Thank you very much C-Pound

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Hit the checkmark at the top left of the answer to mark it as accepted.  Cheers.

Comment: hi C-pound, I have another problem. So i made similar code with yours to count the amount of  lembur (overtime) hours in absen table.

Comment: here is my code,                                                                                                rsabsen.Close
 lembur = "select sum(lmbr) from absen where NIP ='" & cnip & "' and status ='absen keluar' and tglabsen between '" & Text1.Text & "' and '" & Text2.Text & "'"
   rsabsen.Open lembur, KON, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
   countlem = rsabsen(0).Value ///
   tjumlahjamlembur = countlem
   ttunjangan = rsabsen(0).Value * Val(txtlemburperjam.Text)
   ttotalgaji = Val(gaji.Text) + Val(ttunjangan.Text)

Comment: If you have another question, it's best to put it in a separate question rather than junking up this one.